# Propagation of an experimental uncertainty through a function without an inverse

Tags: error-analysis, statistics

I have a function, $y=f(x)$, which cannot be solved for $x$ analytically. For an experimental value of $y$ with an uncertainty, $y_{exp.}\pm\sigma_{y}$, how could a value of $x$ and its $\pm1\sigma$ uncertainty be found? $x$ can be solved for numerically by plotting $y=f(x)$ and projecting onto $x$ at $y=y_{exp}$, but what to quote for the uncertainty on $x$ is not clear to me.

The specific example is shown in the attached plot, with the highlighted region covering $\pm\sigma_y$ centred on $y_{exp.}$. My initial approach would be to take the $\pm1\sigma_x$ region to be from $x\sim0.2$ to $3.3$, which is the $x$-range that is covered by the $\pm1\sigma_y$ region when projected onto the $x$-axis. I don't think this is valid, however, as it assumes $y+\sigma_y=f(x+\sigma_x)$. What to quote as the value of $x$ is also not clear in this case as the function is double valued at $y=y_{exp}$.

I am essentially just looking for an estimate of $x$ and its uncertainty.

[[image: Plot of <span class=]$y=f(x)$, showing experimental measurement of $y$.">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBdC3.png)